# Para que serve a malloc?

Tags: c++

Sou novato em C++ então tenho algumas dúvidas. Uma delas que eu já vi em vários códigos por ai é a função malloc. Para que serve a **malloc**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente `malloc` é uma função introduzida na linguagem C, ela serve para a alocação dinâmica de memória na região conhecida como **memory heap**, uma região continua de espaços na memória principal que o sistema operacional disponibiliza para o seu programa utilizar.
Diferente da alocação estática e da alocação automática, em que o gerenciamento da memória alocada por variáveis é feito pelo compilador juntamente com o linker, mais especificamente  esses utilitários controlam quando a variável deve ser criada - alocada da memória, e destruída - desalocada da memória; a alocação dinâmica, feita por `malloc` no C, é de responsabilidade do programador, sendo esse espaço disponibilizado pelo SO, porém gerenciado pelo programador, gerenciando quando esse espaço deve ser desalocado ou mudado de estado.

No C++ o operador `new`, assim como em outras linguagens, é o equivalente ao `malloc` do C.

PS: Algumas linguagens possuem um "coletor de lixo", onde o programador não necessita se preocupar com o gerenciamento da alocação dinâmica.